# Forecasting Age distribution

Tags: time-series, forecasting

I would like to project the data in this graph for at least 4 or 5 periods. Unfortunately, that won't be possible with a moving average. A regression will result in negative values after the 3rd period. What are my forecasting options?

Basically, what i'm trying to do, is predict where the boomer hump is gonna be based soley on the population and age per year data

**EDIT** AT work we have lots of image sites blocked, [here's the image](http://97.107.136.148/age_dist.jpg) in case you can't see it.

**EDIT 2** Updated Image

[image: State Wide Age Distribution]

Comment: What's wrong with the moving average?

Comment: What's a "period"?  You can always add variables into your model (e.g. to prevent it going to unrealistic values).

Comment: @Shane - each period is 10 years. Age will be the only variable i have for those years

Comment: I understand that age is the only variable that you will have in your data, but you can add additional factors based on priori information (e.g. that population can never be negative).  This is especially true if you model this using a Bayesian approach.

Comment: @Shane - I'm not that advanced yet as to do Bayesian analysis on the data set, but I'm a fast learner :)

Comment: @dassouki: Suppose that an average adult (say between 25 - 40 yrs) gives birth to 2 kids (something you can get from census). Then you can extrapolate using some assumptions: (a) Percentage of adults who have kids (say 60%) etc. Then you can perform a rolling lagged forecast using the number of kids born in 1930s who would be adults in 1960s etc Does that make sense?

Comment: @Sikrant Vadali - Changed image

Comment: @Shane - changed Image

Comment: @Srikant: more detailed data of birth rates (by women grouped into five year age ranges) are readily available for exactly the purpose you propose.  It's best to obtain these data for the particular state in question rather than using nationwide averages.

Answer (score 6):

For demographic forecasting of any quality whatsoever you need to account for birth and death rates and, if possible, migration, breaking them down by gender (at a minimum) and, if possible, by race.  These rates have all changed substantially during your time period and are likely to continue changing in the future.  This information is available on the US Census Bureau's site.  Many states have state-specific mortality tables available.

I have performed such projections at state and even census tract levels with the same aim in mind (to support market research analysis for assisted living facilities) and found that a careful projection will differ substantially from purely statistical (demographically ignorant) procedures like moving averages or regression.

Comment: This is not a US state forecast. I can get the gender, race, income, birth/death data, for the last 10 years only, would that be enough?

Comment: @dassouki: sorry, I saw the "statewide" on the graphic's title and presumed (incorrectly) that it referred to a US state.  The birth/death data for the last 10 years would be excellent, because it will be a reasonably good predictor of birth/death rates into the near future.

Comment: I just discovered that the data I have covers 2 periods in the last 10 years: 2 counts at -5 and -10 years